How to save book object corresponding to particular author object which is already present in db using Spring Boot
I have created one project in spring boot which is book-store . I have one post service which is used to take details of book and author also and save that into db [both book and author at same time].
I want to create a logic where i can save new book for already existing author but i tried several ways and im unable to do.
I need a way to do this

Here what i tried doing is i passed author email in path variable and passing a new book object as a json . i created a service which used to fetch particular author from db and i set that author object to my book object but it is saving that author object again and it is creating duplicate entry for that
author table:
here you can see duplicate entry of same author happend which i dont want

book table:
book table is correct here new book got saved

github link
this is my github link you can take a code and please help me to solve this issue . thanks in advance

Stop using Lombok (at least stop using @Data with JPA as that is a terrible idea, why see this blog written by me -> https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/). Which I suspect is also the cause for your issue.

Based on your Book and Author classes, it seems you have a one-to-one relationship between them. However, to allow an author to have multiple books, you'll need a one-to-many relationship between Author and Book.

author table: here you can see duplicate entry of same author happend
which i dont want

Its because of the one-to-one relationship. This happens because each time you save a new book, it attempts to save the associated author as a new entry.
EDIT
Assuming you updated the relationship to one-to-many, your method should look like this :
public Book addBookToExistingAuthor(String authorEmail, String bookName, int bookRating, String bookCode) {
        // Find the existing author by email
        Author author = authorRepository.findByAuthorEmail(authorEmail)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Author not found"));

        // Create a new book and associate it with the existing author
        Book newBook = new Book();
        newBook.setBookName(bookName);
        newBook.setBookRating(bookRating);
        newBook.setBookCode(bookCode);
        newBook.setAuthor(author);

        // Save the new book
        return bookRepository.save(newBook);
    }


Even after keeping OneToMany relationship i still got the error actually its trying to save same existing author again, but i just need need to save new book for existing author ... if possible can you share code regarding this :-)

Edited @ShubhamNigam
